# define a matrix in a function c++

Tags: c++, matrix

This is my code in ADtest.cpp but when i call this function in mainwindow.cpp it makes an error! i want matrix dynamic with variable sizes of row and column. Honestly i am not good in matrix and pointers and address..
so i am really grateful if somebody helps me and thank you.

```
#include "AD_test.h"
AD_test::AD_test()
{
}
bool AD_test:: test(float s, float *X[Ndft][N], int Ndft, float lambda,  int N)
{
int x=0;
cdf *f0;
f0=0;
float An[Ndft][N];

 for (int k=0; k<N; k++)
{
    cout <<"pour l'échantillon "<<k<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<Ndft;i++)
    {
        An[i][k]=0;
        An[i][k]=-Ndft-((2*i-1)*(log(1-exp(-X[i][k]/(2*sqr(s))*(1+X[i][k]/(2*sqr(s)))))
        +log(1-(1-exp(-X[Ndft+1-i][k]/(2*sqr(s))*(1+X[Ndft+1-i][k]/(2*sqr(s)))))))/Ndft);

        if (An[i][k]>lambda)
        {
           cout << "H1=>signal détecté dans le bin " <<i << endl;
           x++;
        }
        else
          {
            cout <<"H0=>pas de signal dans le bin " <<i<< endl ;
            x--;
          }
     }
  }
  if (x>0)
   return true;
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: in c++ you have std::vector, so you won't have to manage memory and pointers

Comment: /home/hoss/cdf/mainwindow.cpp:46: error: no matching function for call to 'AD_test::test(float&, MainWindow::Matrix**, int&, float&, int&)'
         bool conclusion=stat->test(noise_power,&spectre,Ndft,lambda,Nsamples);
                                                                             ^

Answer (score 0):

Using an array of pointers or double pointer.
In this method also, we must typecast the 2D array when passing to function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Same as "void print(int **arr, int m, int n)"
void print(int *arr[], int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));
}



int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3;
    int n = 3;
    print((int **)arr, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

I think it will be helpful.

Comment: thank you! i had solved this problem but i faced anothor one which it return "inf" as a value and i checked the function and it is true.

Comment: I can't get your problem. Please share your idea/problem clearly.

Comment: int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int l=N/Ndft;
vec An;
    An.set_size(N);
    An.zeros();
for (int k=0; k<l; k++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<Ndft;i++)
        {
           An[k*Ndft+i]=0;

            An[k*Ndft+i]=-Ndft-((2*i-1)*(log(1-exp(-X[k*Ndft+i]/(2*sqr(s))*(1+X[k*Ndft+i]/(2*sqr(s))))) +log(1-(1-exp(-X[Ndft*(k+1)+1-i]/(2*sqr(s))*(1+X[Ndft*(k+1)+1-i]/(2*sqr(s)))))))/Ndft);
           cout<<"An["<<k*Ndft+i<<"]= " <<An[k*Ndft+i]<<endl;
after execution it displays An[i]=inf for all the i !

Comment: Bro, what is "vec X" here?? Please give me calling part of that function where from you call it. Like this-->> int d=test(0.3, vec X,4,0.5,5); as example.